# Ionic Capacitor (or Cordova) - share image to facebook

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I have built an app using Ionic/Angular with Capacitor (but can also use Cordova plugins as it's only for mobile). I am trying to add a feature to share an image on facebook. I tried using the SocialSharing plugin but it doesn't work at all (it raises an error with a list of package names that can be used for sharing, and 'com.facebook.katana' is not amongst them).

I then tried the cordova-plugin-facebook-connect plugin, and I can only share a URL using the showDialog() with a "share" method. Images are not accepted.

I also tried the Capacitor Share plugin, but there is no way to just show facebook as the social network to use...

What I want to achieve is either to present the user with a dialog to share an image to Facebook only with (if possible) a pre-populated text to go along with it, or present the normal "share via" dialog but to be able to establish whether the user chose facebook as the medium and successfully shared the image.

Any help?
Many thanks !

Comment: try this 'https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/share#share' or 'https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing'

Comment: Thanks @RaviAshara but those are the two of the three I tried, as I try to explain above. The SocialSharing.shareViaFacebook() does not work, the plain SocialSharing.share() works but shows all the possible ways to share, and it does not share an image, only URL works. The Capacitor.Share works but again it shows all the possible share options, not just facebook and it cannot be restricted to facebook only. Plus it also does not share an image, just the URL works.....

Comment: What I want to achieve is this: In my app, we have a competition running, and if the user wants an extra participation then he can share the competition on facebook with specific wording and hashtags and win an extra participation. So we need to allow ONLY facebook, and preferably pre-fill the text of the post by the app, and the user of course will be able to see it, change it if he wants and post. So I need to:
1. Allow ONLY facebook or at least KNOW that he shared on facebook from the many available sharing options
2. Pre-fill the text of the post (preferred)
3. Be able to share an IMAGE

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of cordova-plugin-facebook-connect.

It's not possible today to share photos with the plugin, but that will be added in the next major release:

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect/issues/54